# getting a variable from component and injecting in module

Tags: angular

i would like to know if it is possible to get a variable from my component and use it in my module.
In this case i'm configuring a stripe checkout payment with ngx-stripe, this library requires the publish key from stripe like this:

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxStripeModule.forRoot('***your-stripe-publishable-key***'), //<-- here i would like to insert the variable that comes from component.
    LibraryModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This publish key is something that i have stored in my db for each user... so... how can i do it? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is trying to change the publishable key in ngx-stripe. there is a method in stripeService called .changeKey() that allows you to change the current key.

Answer (score 0):

You should check security issues, but i woul try something like this.

In your main.ts before initialization:

```
http.get('endpoint that retrieves key from db')
    .then( response => response.json())
     //use some global variable in a service to save the key.
    .then( response => myService.key = response.key)
     .then(() => plastformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule))
```

Later you can use the global variable set on your service to set the NgxStripeModule.forRoot value.

Comment: Hi there, i've been trying some aproaches about how to change that key in app.module, i tried with enviroment variable even with global variables declared in  typings.d.ts .... but didn't work... after reading deep in the ngx-stripe library, someone added a new method that let you change the current key. so calling stripeService.changeKey() you can pass the new key.

Comment: Great Sergio, glad you find the solution.